# How to stop VS Code from removing Python unused imports on save

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Looking for general advice, as I'm not completely sure what is causing this behavior which I did not encounter until recently. I'm finding it quite annoying because it can delete imports if I comment out a line during development.

Comment: Does it happen in every repository / project? Do you have git pre-commit hooks installed?

Comment: @OferSadan It does happen in every project. I do not believe I have git pre-commit hooks installed. It happens on saving any changes to a file, not on git actions.

Comment: One possible options is to remove the lines you posted and to see if this behavior continues, another option is to remove the extensions you mentioned. Sorry I can't help further

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the following to your settings.json file (you can access it on Windows with ctrl+shift+p followed by a search for settings)

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    ... [other settings] ...
    "source.organizeImports": false
}
```

Note: ensure that "editor.codeActionsOnSave" is not defined elsewhere (aside from language specific places), as this prevented the fix from working the first time I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your extensions might have the **Auto extension or Accessibility extension** installed.

Revert back if this did not work.